# Casting POD object with static_cast

Tags: c++, casting

this is what i mean,

```
class V3
{
public:
float x,y,z;
};

class V3_
{
 public:
float x,y,z;
};

V3_ vec1;
V3 vec2 = static_cast<V3_>(vec1);
```

what should i do to make this cast work in compile time?

Thanks.

edit:

there seems to be some misunderstanding about what i want to do.
i can write an operator to the conversion, but i want it to be done in compile time.

here are two implementations of Vector3 that allows static_cast. i dont know how does it work, but it does work.

http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/OgreVector3_8h_source.html

http://harry-3d-engine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/NxOgreVec3.h

i can do this cast

```
 void DynamicBody::SetLinearMomentum(const Vector3& vel)
 {
body->setLinearMomentum(static_cast<NxOgre::Vec3>(vel));
 }
```

i would like an explanation on how i can do this.

**edit:**

upon further investigation i found how it actually does this,
it calls

```
template<class user_xyz_vector_type>
inline user_xyz_vector_type as() const { ... }
```

that is not an actual static_cast, but compiler accepts it as one.
i really hoped casting pods to eachother was an actual thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cast will not work at any time. You can't `static_cast` completely unrelated and not convertible types to each other.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, so I don't know what the work "work" means in this case, but at a raw memory level the conversion can be performed by `reinterpret_cast`

```
V3 vec2 = reinterpret_cast<V3_&>(vec1);
```

but this is an ugly hack that is not guaranteed to work, since, again, your types are unrelated. With the same degree (or even better) of success you can simply `memcpy` one object into another.

Comment: `memcpy` is better, even. It's guaranteed to work provided that `V3` and `V3_` have the same layout, and normally that will be the same for a given compiler, there's no reason to lay them out differently. With the `reinterpret_cast` you are at the mercy of whether the optimizer takes advantage of the strict aliasing rules: you could easily end up with code that works at `-O1` and fails at `-O3`, depending where and when `vec1` is initialized.

Comment: @mikbal: `reinterpret_cast` might easily fail for the reasons described in Steve Jessop's comment.

Answer (score 1):

You could avoid using cast altogether as:

```
V3 vec2 = {vec1.x, vec1.y, vec1.z};
```

Or write conversion function:

```
V3 to_V3(V3_ const & v)
{
   V3 v3 = {v.x, v.y, v.z};
   return v3;
}
```

and use it as:

```
V3 vec2 = to_V3(vec1);
```

Comment: Ideal (and I'm being picky here) would be something that either continues to work correctly or else stops compiling when a fourth data member is added to both classes. Your `to_V3` function could have one or more static asserts in it, sufficient to ensure `V3` doesn't have any extra data members unaccounted for.

Comment: @SteveJessop: static assert on the sizes of the both classes, or something else also?

Comment: I was thinking that the class sizes are the same, and (for this example) that the sum of the sizes of the fields you copy is equal to the class size. If a class has padding in it, and someone adds a new data member that fits inside that padding, then you're never going to detect it by looking at sizes. So my suggestion isn't perfect in all cases, but it shouldn't produce any false alarms for a structure consisting of multiple floats.

Answer (score 1):

The types are unrelated, therefore you need `reinterpret_cast` :

```
V3_ vec1;
V3 vec2 = reinterpret_cast<V3_&>(vec1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
V3_ vec1;
V3 vec2 = *(V3*)&vec1;
```

EDIT: still, you know that's probably not a good thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

To `static_cast` `V3` to `V3_` use `public:` on `V3` class declaration.
`class V3 : public V3_`. This way you can convert objects. Use virtual deconstructors if you want polymorphism and you're aware of what you're doing.

Comment: If you're going to change the definition of `V3` then you probably might as well just `typedef V3_ V3;` ;-)

Comment: Not if V3_ had different functions and types than V3. That is most likely a sub-class type cast like `class A : public B` `class B` `void B::function() { A* p= ((A*)this); }` instead of object typedef